# Getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS' when running Google Sheets API quickstart

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm following this guide https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Upon running the sample code they provided (The only thing I changed was the location of the api secret since we already had one set up and the APPLICATION_NAME) I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS'
```

Log before the error

```
  File "generate_report.py", line 2, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/Users/HarshaGoli/Git/PantherBot/scripts/calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 25, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from oauth2client import transport
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 255, in <module>
    redirections=httplib2.DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS,
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and investigated on the problem.
In my case, it was caused by a file named ''calendar.py" in the same directory.
It's said you should avoid using general names that can be used for standard python library.

Answer (score 1):

It may be versioning problem. It could be `python3` version of  `httplib2` which cause troubles, try to follow answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941042/google-cloud-function-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-defaul/49970238#49970238)