# Google Cloud Function - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, cron-task, google-app-engine-python

I'm using Appengine cron job to schedule cloud function and when I deploy and try to run a job, getting below error. Any idea what could be wrong here? Followed steps from [here][1]

```
(/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~zion-hymns/20180222t221057.407849847593018575/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pubsub_utils
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~zion-hymns/20180222t221057.407849847593018575/pubsub_utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    import oauth2client.contrib.appengine as gae_oauth2client
  File "./lib/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.py", line 36, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "./lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from oauth2client import transport
  File "./lib/oauth2client/transport.py", line 255, in <module>
    redirections=httplib2.DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS'


  [1]: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html?utm_campaign=culture_education_functions_en_06-29-17&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=yt-desc
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Before it had the error `ImportError: No module named httplib2` and once I installed in local the python dependencies via `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` and deployed again, I have the same stack trace.

Comment: same here, tries to install older versions of google-api-python-client , no use. Seems like some nasty stuff happening on google's side.

Comment: did anyone found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 7):

Seems that I found the problem. Which version of Python your `pip` is using? In my case it was `3.6` despite the fact that the Python itself was 2.7

So the problem was that `pip` downloaded a `Python 3.6` syntax version of `httplib2`, it was uploaded to the Google App Engine, which use Python 2.7. It tried to load in the module and fail miserably.

Try this :

1. Check the vesionn of your pip with :

**pip -V**

If you see some thing like pip 9.0.1 from `/bla/bla/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)` then continue

2. Install `pip` for python 2.7 (it should be in the Python2.7 installation pachage under bin folder)
3. Remove old `lib` folder in your project
4. Run `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` (make sure that this pip is the right `2.7` version)
5. Deploy

By doing that you are using the right version of the lib and it should be working.

Hope it will help.