# Error in gcloud " AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS'"

Tags: python-2.7, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement firebase functions cron job from this link : https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron

Everything worked properly
But when I try to run google cloud cron job it gives me below error :

```
 (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/c5586dbb532f7e5f_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/c5586dbb532f7e5f_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/c5586dbb532f7e5f_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/c5586dbb532f7e5f_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~debitcredit-7ecc0/20180506t121449.409523654918066893/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pubsub_utils
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~debitcredit-7ecc0/20180506t121449.409523654918066893/pubsub_utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    import oauth2client.contrib.appengine as gae_oauth2client
  File "./lib/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.py", line 36, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "./lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 39, in <module>
    from oauth2client import transport
  File "./lib/oauth2client/transport.py", line 255, in <module>
    redirections=httplib2.DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS'
```

I tried this solution : [Getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS' when running Google Sheets API quickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875358/getting-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-default-max-redirects)

But still no luck.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your `httplib` Module.

When you installed this module for your project you must have installed it with pip for `Python 3`

If you want to check whether this module is for `python 3 or python 2`,

Go to `httplib2 module` and go inside its `init.py`
later see this line `Requires Python 3 or later`

if it is written like that means you have installed this library with pip for python 3. Now delete all the httplib2 from your lib folder.

Create a seperate enviroment for python 2.7 and again install all your modules with `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank you so much for a simple explanantion. I was totally Confused.